# how to make ion-option be chosen upon tap instead of clicking OK

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am working on a mobile app and I have a scenario where I used `ion-option` with `ion-select` which works fine. However, I want to eliminate the OK/CANCEL button such that I do not have to click any of this buttons to select my option.

What I want is being able to tap an option and it gets selected automatically without having to click OK.

form.html

```
      <ion-card class="card-space">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label stacked>Title</ion-label> 
          <ion-select multiple="false" text-wrap>
            <ion-option>Mr</ion-option>
            <ion-option>Mrs</ion-option>
            <ion-option>Miss</ion-option>
            <ion-option>Dr</ion-option>
            <ion-option>Arch</ion-option>
            <ion-option>Bishop</ion-option>
            <ion-option>Pst</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is set the `interface` property.

```
<ion-select multiple="false" interface="popover" text-wrap>
 <ion-option>Mr</ion-option>
 <ion-option>Mrs</ion-option>
 <ion-option>Miss</ion-option>
 <ion-option>Dr</ion-option>
 <ion-option>Arch</ion-option>
 <ion-option>Bishop</ion-option>
 <ion-option>Pst</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

In general you can figure out the details for the ionic directives under their [API section](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/).